# How do I reduce the padding around a FusionCharts pie chart?

Tags: fusioncharts

I would like to have a pie chart fill a square chart area, currently I can't get it to use more than ~50% of the area, there's lots of grey space all around it. I have tried setting the `margin` and `spacing` attributes but it makes no difference.

Is there a way to reduce the padding between the pie chart and the grey box?

[image: How do I remove all the grey space around this chart?]

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var demographicsChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie3d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      chart: {
        paletteColors: "#FFAE00,#1566EC,#82C309",
        bgColor: "#ffffff",
        use3DLighting: 1,
        showShadow: 0,
        enableSmartLabels: 0,
        startingAngle: 90,
        showLabels: 0,
        showValues: 0,
        showPercentValues: 0,
        showLegend: 0,
        pieSliceDepth: 20,
        pieYScale: 70,
        bgcolor: "EEEEEE,FFFFFF",
        bgalpha: "100,100",
        bgratio: "0,100",
        bgangle: "90",
        showBorder: 1,
        borderColor: 1,
        borderColor: "DDDDDD",
        borderThickness: 1,
        showToolTip: 0,
        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        animation: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      },
      "data": [{
        "label": "Not Started",
        "value": 13
      }, {
        "label": "Complete",
        "value": 9
      }, {
        "label": "In Progress",
        "value": 33
      }]
    }
  });
  demographicsChart.render();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
#chart-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, FusionCharts XT automatically calculates the best fit pie radius for the chart. But if you want to enforce one of your own values, you can use the attribute "pieRadius". The value is a number which represents the outer radius of the chart. It is mentioned in the docs here http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-attr-pie3d.html.

I have created a fiddle for you with increased radius. Let me know if this helps. 
http://jsfiddle.net/subramaniashiva/ZjyJT/7/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var demographicsChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie3d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        chart: {
            paletteColors: "#FFAE00,#1566EC,#82C309",
            bgColor: "#ffffff",
            use3DLighting: 1,
            showShadow: 0,
            enableSmartLabels: 0,
            startingAngle: 90,
            showLabels: 0,
            showValues: 0,
            showPercentValues: 0,
            showLegend: 0,
            pieSliceDepth: 20,
            pieYScale: 70,
            bgcolor: "EEEEEE,FFFFFF",
            bgalpha: "100,100",
            bgratio: "0,100",
            bgangle: "90",
            showBorder: 1,
            borderColor: "DDDDDD",
            borderThickness: 1,
            showToolTip: 0,
            animation: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            pieRadius: 148
        },
            "data": [{
            "label": "Not Started",
                "value": 13
        }, {
            "label": "Complete",
                "value": 9
        }, {
            "label": "In Progress",
                "value": 33
        }]
    }
});
demographicsChart.render();
});
```

Comment: Hey, Can you please tell me how can I do the same with gauge chart?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be only a partial answer. If you want to display the pie values on the chart, there are two problems:

1. Values cannot be displayed inside the chart. Is there no method for this?
   and
2. Values that displayed outside the chart have a large amount of padding between the value and the chart. Is there any method to reduce that space?

Comment: Placing values inside the pie slices are not supported. Though you can force it by negative value in labelDistance attribute. But remember, if you rotate the pie, The label will be displaced. Its a kind of partial hack. You should look for the [attribute](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=pie2d) section of Pie. You can get lot of insight.